# transformations in ros / rviz?

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i'm quite new to ros and am using rviz to display my point cloud which i have manipulated a little bit using pcl. by manipulated i only applied a voxel grid thereby reducing the number of points.

but my question is, how can i apply a transformation when using rviz? i was able to do it when using only pcl but now that i'm using ros and visualizing it all in rviz, i'm getting compiler errors for just #include pcl/common/transforms.h which is of course, stopping my transformation and translation from working.

or maybe transformations and translations are not necessary in ros? but there must be a way right?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27746/transformations-in-ros-/-rviz?/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [`pcl_ros`](http://ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) package provides transforms for PCL point clouds.

Typically, you would add a `<depend package="pcl_ros"/>` to your `manifest.xml`, then:

```
 #include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2012-02-19**:
thanks very much, worked great!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Transformations in ROS are handled with the tf library.

For rviz you need to publish whatever entity you have using a known frame_id.
In addition someone needs to publish a transformation from the currently set fixed_frame to this frame_id. rviz will then display correctly.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1